# How to check if linux distribution support systemd in rpm spec file?

Tags: systemd, rpm-spec

I want to add one systemd service into a RPM package.
In order to be backward compatible for those os version not support systemd yet, I wanna judge if current OS support systemd in RPM spec file.

Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the RPM for different distributions and the `%{dist}` tag in the release, e.g. `Release: 3%{?dist}`. See [Fedora's page describing the tag](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag), along with some other conditional flags you can use in your `%files` section to decide which files to drop in.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I solved this issue by OS distribution predefined macros. For my case opensuse and sles, they have a macro named %suse_version in /usr/lib/rpm/suse/macros.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no standard macros for your use case.

You could however check if %{_unitdir} is defined but that's a really sloppy thing to do, as the relevant package that defines this macro might not be installed by default on the build system.